# Python package is failing because it doesn't see the setuptools

Tags: python-3.x, linux, python-packaging

I am trying to create a python environment on a server that is not connected to the public internet, so i have downloaded and transfered all the neccessary packages to the server and trying to install with the following command `python3 -m pip install --no-index --find-links=opt/executor/xxx/ packagename`

So my question is that when i try to install python-dateutil-2.7.5.tar.gz
im getting the below output saying that setuptools is not installed even though it is installed.

Would you know how i can fix this issue?
Python 3.6.13 is installed on a linux machine

```
[root@cdddd xx]# python3 -m pip install --no-index --find-links=opt/executor/xxx/ python-dateutil-2.7.5.tar.gz
Looking in links: opt/executor/xxx/
Processing ./python-dateutil-2.7.5.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-v5h9rus9 --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index --find-links opt/executor/xxx/ -- setuptools>=38.2.5 wheel:
  Looking in links: opt/executor/xxx/
  Collecting setuptools>=38.2.5
    Url 'opt/executor/xxx/' is ignored. It is either a non-existing path or lacks a specific scheme.
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=38.2.5 (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for setuptools>=38.2.5

  ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-v5h9rus9 --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index --find-links opt/executor/xxx/ -- setuptools>=38.2.5 wheel" failed with error code 1 in None
```

Setuptool install

```
[root@ddd7 xx]# python3 -m pip install --no-index --find-links=opt/executor/xxx/ setuptools-38.2.5.zip
Looking in links: opt/executor/xxx/
Processing ./setuptools-38.2.5.zip
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 38.2.5
    Uninstalling setuptools-38.2.5:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-38.2.5
  Running setup.py install for setuptools ... done
Successfully installed setuptools-38.2.5
```

Comment: python-dateutil : Latest is `python-dateutil-2.8.1.tar.gz` https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/ed/5bbc91f03fa4c839c4c7360375da77f9659af5f7086b7a7bdda65771c8e0/python-dateutil-2.8.1.tar.gz .... No issues, python3.

Comment: hi yes it is but i need the version that i need for a software.